# How can I restore the login screen?

Tags: login, gdm

I used "Ubuntu Tweak" to deactivate the login/users screen in order to save time (with not giving the password). It worked. It was ok. But now i need to create another user. I did create another user and  I went back to "Ubuntu Tweak"; i reset the option about showing the login/users screen, but it does not work. After starting up my machine, it goes directly to my account, showing me my desktop.

How can i restore the login/users screen?
(i have tried uninstalling/purging Ubuntu Tweak and reinstalling it, but nothing changed)

Comment: I found this: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/03/automatically-logon-ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal-typing-passwords/
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Open a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run this command (by pasting it into the Terminal and pressing enter):

```
sudo mv /etc/gdm/custom.conf /etc/gdm/custom.conf.old
```

You may be prompted for your password. As you enter it, you won't see any placeholder characters (like `*`). That's OK--just type it in and press enter.

Then when you reboot, you should see the login screen.

Please note that this answer does depend on the version of Ubuntu you are running. Ubuntu 11.04 and previous use GDM, so the above technique should work. Later versions of Ubuntu use LightDM instead, so the above technique should not be used with them.

Also, if you'd like to be automatically logged in to one user, but want to retain the ability to use another user account, you can do that--you can still log out or switch users, after you've been automatically logged in.

Answer (score 1):

I remember having this exact same problem.

I solved it by going to user accounts, my user account was set to log in automatically - changing this required a password at the next log out.

Answer (score 0):

You ca get back the Default Login Screen using Light DM Manager which you can get from here[Simple Light DM Manager](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20319611/simple-lightdm-manager_0.2-public4ubuntu1_all.deb)